# mapping two data frames using one common column

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two data frames, (FYI created one using Groupby)
I want to map data array x which looks like the below

Fruit  #
Apple  2
Pear   5
lemon  1

into Data Frame y which looks like the below

Date Fruit Cost
Mon  Apple 1.00
Mon  Pear  2.00
Tues lemon 1.50
Tues Apple 1.00

When mapping into y I want to create new column called #. so the final outcome should look like the below

Date   Fruit  Cost  #
Mon    Apple  1.00  2
Mon    Pear   2.00  5
Tues   lemon  1.50  1
Tues   Apple  1.00  2

I have tried using the below

y['#'] = np.where(y['Fruit'].map(x.set_index('Fruit')['#']))

however this kicks out valueerror:Length of values does not match length of index.

The length of both data arrays could vary as well depending on the underlying data. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Thanks